# Destroy slider in print window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i want to run this code only when i want to take a print by pressing CTRL+p or clicking button  " `a href="javascript:window.print()" "`

```
$(".slider").slick('unslick');
```

Comment: Please provide more in this question, a JSFiddle so people can test and provide some of the JavaScript and HTML. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you can do this is by check for the beforePrint event and doing `.unslick()` when that event is happening.

Here is an example that i've come up with to show you how to do this:

```
$(function () {
    var $panel = $('<div class="panel">13</div>');
    var slickOpts = {
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4,
        dots: true,
        prevArrow: '.btn-prev',
        nextArrow: '.btn-next'
    };
    // Init the slick
    $('#dashboard').slick(slickOpts);

    var beforePrint = function() {
        $('#dashboard').slick('unslick');
    };
    var afterPrint = function() {
        console.log('Functionality to run after printing');
    };

    if (window.matchMedia) {
        var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
        mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
            if (mql.matches) {
                beforePrint();
            } else {
                afterPrint();
            }
        });
    }

    window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
    window.onafterprint = afterPrint;

});
```

[**JSFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vwq7vg1x/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to do, you could just use a media query or a separate CSS file set to `print` media to apply different styles for printing.

```
@media print {
    .slider: {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what 'unslick' does exactly, but if you are just trying to hide some elements on the page, you could do that with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned jQuery didn't work in every occasion, so I manipulated it with CSS.

This worked for me on slick.js version 1.8.0

```
@media print {
  .slick-track {
    flex-direction: column !important;
  }
  .slick-list {
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
  .slick-slider .slick-track,
  .slick-slider .slick-list {
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    transform: none !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
  .slick-track .slick-slide {
    display: block !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
  .slick-arrow,
  .slick-dots,
  .slick-track .slick-cloned {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```